# How to set vertical alignment for mdRadioButton directive of Angular Material related to text?

Tags: html, css, material-design, angular-material

How to set vertical alignment for `mdRadioButton` directive of `Angular Material` related to text?
I have tried both `layout-align` and `vertical-align` style but, the radio button is always align middle related to the text.

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tOmPZ9wST1P44crxKyRw?p=preview) is the plunker

```
<md-content>
    <md-radio-group ng-model="data"  style="vertical-align:top;">
        <md-radio-button value="a" aria-label="Label 1" style="vertical-align:text-top;">long text 1</md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button value="b"> long text 2 </md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular Material actually generates a container for the radio button's on/off state and ripple.

`<md-radio-button>` is the parent and `_md-container` is the child element you want to modify.

[Here's a fork of the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjDWBMoZRwSlyzm1QEnM?p=preview) with the modified styles:

```
md-radio-button ._md-container {
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice. I'd suggest `top: 5px;`, just for a better alignment. Also, it is worth mentioning that the middle-alignment was due to `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);`.

Comment: Thank you Kelbster

Comment: Is there a way to do this natively within the material element tag? My project is using tailwind, so I don't have css files to work with.

Answer (score 1):

For Angular it can be achieved by:

```
mat-radio-button .mat-radio-label-content {
    white-space: normal;
}

mat-radio-button .mat-radio-label {
    align-items: normal;
}
```

Live Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkjhrz?embed=1&file=styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @athlan's answer slightly...

It's better to only set the vertical alignment on the radio button element and not the label too, otherwise non-wrapping labels don't align properly.

Also I use an additional class selector to opt-in to this behaviour: (sass)

```css
.mat-radio-button.wrapping-radio-button {
  & .mat-radio-container {
    align-self: normal;
  }

  & .mat-radio-label-content {
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
```

In the template...

```html
<mat-radio-button class="wrapping-radio-button">
```