# angular2 material md-radio vertical

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

How to make an angular 2 material `md-radio` button vertical and change and default colour. I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893364/how-to-set-vertical-alignment-for-mdradiobutton-directive-of-angular-material-re) and I was not able to make it display vertically

my code:-

```
<md-radio-group  ng-model="data.group1" layout-align="start start">
    <md-radio-button ng-value="green" class="my-radio" *ngFor="let schedule of schedules" value={{schedule}} (click)="postSchedule(schedule)" ng-style="{'display':'list-item'}">{{schedule}}</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

css:-

```
md-radio-button ._md-container {
   top: 0;
   transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try doing like how [Angular Material2](https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio) does it in the `Examples` tab?

Comment: I have angular Material itself, I have refactored the code as per my requirement.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't mix `angular2` with `angularjs-material`!

Comment: yup, thanks for the suggestion. Made required code change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to try to use flex-box properties. Try below code

```
.my-radio {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex-box;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Scados it worked fine. Can I know how to change the default colour like another colour instead of default colour pink?

Comment: Yes, you can inspect the element with your browser and change it with your own style. You may need to make change for the other css values to.

Answer (score 0):

Cf deleted post on this page by [Pengyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579471/pengyy) which works for me:

You can add a custom style as below for md-radio-group.

```
.radio-group {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```